# Get Title when input URL on UITextField on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextBox box, I enter the URL of a website into that box. Then click Next. I want to get the Title of the website I entered the URL above without using UIWebView, someone can help me.

Comment: Use something like `URLSession` to download the content, then you'll need a parser to parse the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way could be something like this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285248/get-title-when-input-url-on-uitextfield-on-swift-4") else { return }

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    if let content = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let range = content.range(of: "<title>.*?</title>", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) {
                let title = content[range].replacingOccurrences(of: "</?title>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                print(title) // prints "ios - Get Title when input URL on UITextField on swift 4 - Stack Overflow"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote but you should always use URLSession for downloading data asynchronously. Btw this assumes the content returned by the url will always be utf8 encoded

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for your input! Regarding the encoding you're right. I just assumed `.utf8` here. That's why I talked about "One simple way" in my answer. I'm not sure about the asynchronous stuff though. In most cases `URLSession` is the way to go, yeah. But since in this case there is no specific `URLRequest` needed or something and it's just about getting the content I used the `contentsOf` initializer. What other use case is there for an initializer like this if not this one?

Comment: Is there some specific resource stating that it should just be used with local files?

Comment: I can't find anything on the `String` initializer but if you look at the `Data` initializer you will find **Important
Don't use this synchronous initializer to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.
Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the dataTask(with:completionHandler:) method of the URLSession class.**

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I call the initializer from a different thread in my solution I thought it might be ok in this case.

Comment: I have seen cases where the server would not allow synchronous calls even from a background thread